# How to add a CTE to improve stored procedure performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

I have a stored procedure that looks like the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Schema].[ProcName]
    (@PhoneNum  VARCHAR(100)
     @EmailAddr VARCHAR(100)
     @DriverLic VARCHAR(100)
     @EligiblityDate VARCHAR(10))
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Phone BIT = 0,
            @Email BIT = 0,
            @License BIT = 0

    IF (SELECT Value FROM Table 
        WHERE Product = 'ProductA' 
          AND @EligibilityDate BETWEEN EligStart AND EligEnd 
          AND ProductType = 1 
          AND Value = @PhoneNum 
          AND IsActive = 1) 
        SET @Phone = 1

    IF (SELECT Value FROM Table 
        WHERE Product = 'ProductA' 
          AND @EligibilityDate BETWEEN EligStart AND EligEnd 
          AND ProductType = 2 
          AND Value = @EmailAddr 
          AND IsActive = 1) 
        SET @Email = 1

    IF (SELECT Value FROM Table 
        WHERE Product = 'ProductA' 
          AND @EligibilityDate BETWEEN EligStart AND EligEnd 
          AND ProductType = 3 
          AND Value = @DriverLic 
          AND IsActive = 1) 
        SET @License = 1

    SELECT 
        @Phone AS Phone,
        @Email AS Email,
        @License AS License;

    RETURN 0;
```

I was hoping to improve the performance of this query possible by using a CTE. However, I'm not sure how to go about this as I have never used a CTE before.

Comment: Hi there - you're *much* more likely to get a good response from answerers if you post working code, then ask about how you want to change it. The above will break in a number of ways, and you should always look to get working code before you optimize. You should take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the help center for future questions.

Comment: is this a working query / Stored Procedure  ? You are double declaring `@PhoneNum` in the input parameter and inside the SP. Also there are mismatch BEGIN-END

Comment: @Squirrel - I just fixed some of the code, it's working in production. I just tried to write a simplified version as opposed to posting the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

So, for this a CTE will do you no good. CTEs are for when you have re-used subselects in one query, or if you're trying to do something recursive, and they're frequently not as useful as we'd like them to be. For the complexity of your queries, I'd worry about just getting the foundational stuff straight in your head first, and worry about CTEs when you find yourself needing them, rather than reaching for them without a compelling reason.

What I think you need here is something more like the following:

```
Create Procedure [Schema].[ProcName]
    (@PhoneNum   VARCHAR(100),
    @EmailAddr  VARCHAR(100),
    @DriverLic  VARCHAR(100),
    @EligiblityDate VARCHAR(10))
AS
BEGIN

    select
        max(case when ProductType = 1 and [Value] = @PhoneNum then 1 else 0 end) as PhoneNum,
        max(case when ProductType = 2 and [Value] = @EmailAddr then 1 else 0 end) as EmailAddr,
        max(case when ProductType = 3 and [Value] = @DriverLic then 1 else 0 end) as DriverLic
    from [Table]
    WHERE
        Product = 'ProductExample'
        AND @EligibilityDate BETWEEN EligStart and EligEnd
        AND IsActive = 1
END
```

This has a similar effect of joining together your multiple queries (you're right to be suspicious when you're duplicating code like that!) into a single query, but there's no need for a subselect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Schema].[ProcName]
    (@PhoneNum  VARCHAR(100),
     @EmailAddr VARCHAR(100),
     @DriverLic VARCHAR(100),
     @EligiblityDate VARCHAR(10))
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Phone BIT = 0,
            @Email BIT = 0,
            @License BIT = 0

    SELECT @Phone = case when ProductType = 1 and Value = @PhoneNum then 1 else 0 end,
        @Email = case when ProductType = 2 and Value = @EmailAddr then 1 else 0 end,
        @License = case when ProductType = 3 and Value = @DriverLic then 1 else 0 end
    FROM Table 
        WHERE Product = 'ProductA' 
          AND @EligibilityDate BETWEEN EligStart AND EligEnd 
          AND ProductType = 1 

    SELECT 
        @Phone AS Phone,
        @Email AS Email,
        @License AS License;

    RETURN 0;
END
```